# Stretching an Image while preserving the corners in HTML5

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve the effect described in the following question, but using CSS.
I remember seeing somewhere that this now can be done with HTML5, but now can't find the property name.

[Stretching an UIImage while preserving the corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879817/stretching-an-uiimage-while-preserving-the-corners)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use 3 different images.

First, go into photoshop or Gimp or something and break the arrow image you have into 3 parts. The left side with the curve, and the right side with the arrow part. Save them as 3 different images.

Once you've got your images. Create one HTML image element:

```
<img src="img-middle.jpg" />
```

In your CSS, apply styling to the before and after pseudo-elements and add the two image bits that you don't want stretched.

```
img:before {
    contents: '';
    background: url('img-left.jpg');
    height: 50px;
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
}

img:after {
    content: '';
    background: url('img-right.jpg');
    height: 50px;
    width: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -40px;
}
```

Make sure you change the width, height, left and right values to match the width and height of your two image files. This CSS allows these bits of the image to be added on to the left and right sides, no matter how wide the  element is stretched. It's also cool since it's only one element, so the CSS stays pretty clean except for the requirement of the empty content:''; property.

So then you can stretch your middle image element dynamically. Lets say you want he arrow to stretch, have some jQuery that animates the width of the  element, then the middle part will stretch and the corners will stay intact since they're technically not part of the original element, they're just appended.

ETA: As for the method described in the objective-C related post, there's no CSS property that breaks apart images like that unless it's in some obscure webkit nightly build that I've never heard of. Your option here is to break apart the other two sides. You could also combine the left and right portions of your image into a sprite and use the background-position:; CSS property to select bits of the image so that way you'd only have two image file requests, as you want to keep those low to speed up page load time.

Comment: This is a good answer, but not suitable in my case because I need the size of the images to be dynamic and when you have things like right: -40px; it can't scale dynamically.

Comment: Oh, so you need the left/right portions to be dynamic also? So it works for any size image with the same CSS?

Comment: I have 3 images: left one I want to be(width auto & height 100%) middle one(width 100% & height 100%) right one (width auto & height 100%). Now the problem is that the middle one overlaps the right and left and I don't see how I can prevent the overlapping...

Comment: Forgot to add that the images are set as background images

Comment: Just add position:relative; left:-100%; to the left one and position:relative; right:-100%; to the right one.

Answer (score 1):

you can create an element, assign pseudo elements to it for the left and right side caps, and use a CSS3 transition applied to the width property in order to achieve this effect.

i've set up a [working demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/MhDVR/) to illustrate how it's done. this demo uses background colors, but one could use images as well (repeating along the X axis for the center element).

check out the [HTML5 rocks playground](http://playground.html5rocks.com/), you'll find some fascinating snippets demonstrating the power of CSS3 and HTML5 (naturally) and can use it as a quick reference as well.

Comment: You use border-radius, try using 3 images instead, one for left up and down corners, one for middle stretching but not overlapping the corner images and the third image for the right up and down corners. All this needs to have dynamic height and of course dynamic width.

Comment: you can't achieve dynamic height if using a single image for the side caps.

Comment: But my original question was about new option in HTML5, I remember seeing this, but can't find it now

Comment: Thanks, but it is not an answer to my question

Comment: it's HTML5 and it may be used with images. i believe it's one possible solution to the question.

Comment: There's no HTML5 element that allows you to select part of an image, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean CSS3?

I think `border-image` is pretty much what you're looking for.  It lets you take a single image and transform it into the border of an element.

It's kinda hard to work with, so Mozilla made a wonderful WYSIWYG editor:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Border-image_generator