# How to stretch a UIImageView without stretching the center?

Tags: iphone, ios

[image]

I want to stretch the left and right sides of the picture shown above, and keep the middle arrow unstretched.  How can I do that?

Comment: Did you solve this problem without using extra images? if yes, please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Photoshop or another image editing tool to split the image into two pieces: edge and center. The edge image can be one pixel wide and used for left and right edges; the center is however many pixels wide that capture the arrow. You can then put three `UIImageView` instances next to each other: left edge, center, and right edge. The left and right edges are resized to the desired width, while the center keeps its original dimensions.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't like to bother Photoshop and if the image has not to by dynamically resized, you can use my category method on UIImage.

Your sample image named "17maA.png" is 124 px wide. So you can easily create a 300 px wide version with this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"17maA"];
UIImage *newImage = [image pbResizedImageWithWidth:300 andTiledAreaFrom:10 to:20 andFrom:124-20 to:124-10];
```

This is the category method:

```
- (UIImage *)pbResizedImageWithWidth:(CGFloat)newWidth andTiledAreaFrom:(CGFloat)from1 to:(CGFloat)to1 andFrom:(CGFloat)from2 to:(CGFloat)to2  {
    NSAssert(self.size.width < newWidth, @"Cannot scale NewWidth %f > self.size.width %f", newWidth, self.size.width);

    CGFloat originalWidth = self.size.width;
    CGFloat tiledAreaWidth = (newWidth - originalWidth)/2;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(originalWidth + tiledAreaWidth, self.size.height), NO, self.scale);

    UIImage *firstResizable = [self resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, from1, 0, originalWidth - to1) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeTile];
    [firstResizable drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, originalWidth + tiledAreaWidth, self.size.height)];

    UIImage *leftPart = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(newWidth, self.size.height), NO, self.scale);

    UIImage *secondResizable = [leftPart resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, from2 + tiledAreaWidth, 0, originalWidth - to2) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeTile];
    [secondResizable drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, self.size.height)];

    UIImage *fullImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return fullImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. One small change I made was to round up the tiledAreaWidth, like this: CGFloat tiledAreaWidth = ceil((newWidth - originalWidth)/2.0); Otherwise this can result in slight gaps in the resulting image.

Comment: Only size is increasing at left side not right side. How can I stretch both (left  & right) sides with equal width(size)?

Answer (score 4):

[Klaas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/292145/klaas)'s answer really helped me, same in Swift 3.0:

```
static func stretchImageSides(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    guard image.size.width < newWidth else {
        return image
    }

    let originalWidth = image.size.width
    let tiledAreaWidth = ceil(newWidth - originalWidth) / 2.0;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: originalWidth + tiledAreaWidth, height: image.size.height),
                                           false, image.scale)

    let firstResizable = image.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,
                                                                          left: 0,
                                                                          bottom: 0,
                                                                          right: originalWidth - 3),
                                              resizingMode: .stretch)
    firstResizable.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: originalWidth + tiledAreaWidth, height: image.size.height))

    let leftPart = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: image.size.height),
                                           false, image.scale)

    let secondResizable = leftPart?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,
                                                                              left: tiledAreaWidth + originalWidth - 3,
                                                                              bottom: 0,
                                                                              right: 0),
                                              resizingMode: .stretch)
    secondResizable?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: image.size.height))

    let fullImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return fullImage
}
```

- You just need to provide an image, with desired new Width, it will do the horizontal stretching for you.

Answer (score 1):

(Not much help, but there is support for the opposite: stretching an image's centre and keeping the edge parts the same size: see [Stretching an UIImage while preserving the corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879817/stretching-an-uiimage-while-preserving-the-corners).)

**To cook up your own solution,** you can could create a component that contains three parts: a left image, central image, right image. Then you handle size changes to your component by ensuring the central part remains the same width, while the left/right components (images) stretch.

**Alternative strategy:** create a component that is two images stacked on top of each other. The lower image is the flat bar bit (without triangle) and stretches horizontally to fill the available space. The upper image is the triangle central part, and is centred in the available space. This would give the effect you're looking for.

Also, there's an app (not free!) that helps you create nice components with stretchable qualities: [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Arashk's answer, a Swift `UIImage` extension that takes a `size` parameter.

The center of the streched image is still centered.

```swift
extension UIImage {

  func strechedImageSides(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    guard size.width < newSize.width || size.height < newSize.height else {
      return self
    }

    let originalWidth = size.width
    let originalHeight = size.height

    let tiledAreaWidth  = ceil(newSize.width  - originalWidth)  / 2.0
    let tiledAreaHeight = ceil(newSize.height - originalHeight) / 2.0

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: originalWidth + tiledAreaWidth,
                                                  height: originalHeight + tiledAreaHeight),
                                           false,
                                           scale)

    let bottomRightResizable = resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,
                                                                                left: 0,
                                                                                bottom: originalHeight - 1,
                                                                                right: originalWidth - 1),
                                                    resizingMode: .stretch)
    bottomRightResizable.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0,
                                         y: 0,
                                         width: originalWidth + tiledAreaWidth,
                                         height: originalHeight + tiledAreaHeight))

    let topLefthPart = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize,
                                           false,
                                           scale)

    let topLeftResizable = topLefthPart?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: tiledAreaHeight + originalHeight - 1,
                                                                                    left: tiledAreaWidth + originalWidth - 1,
                                                                                    bottom: 0,
                                                                                    right: 0),
                                                        resizingMode: .stretch)

    topLeftResizable?.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))

    let fullImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return fullImage
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

We can stretch the image using the below code :-
Here we need the arrow mark portion must be in same size so we stretch the middle portion below the arrow mark start(assume it will 2 px)

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img_loginButton.png"];
    UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets;
    edgeInsets.left = 0.0f;
    edgeInsets.top = 2.0f;
    edgeInsets.right = 0.0f;
    edgeInsets.bottom = 0.0f;
    image = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:edgeInsets];
//Use this image as your controls image
```

Comment: The OP was wanting to stretch the left and right sides, not top and bottom.

Comment: The top/bottom insets only affect vertical stretching. That doesn't somehow cause the arrow to be ignored when stretching horizontally. If you actually try this, the arrow will end up being stretched out as you resize horizontally.