# Stretch UIImage while keep the center of the image not changed in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I want to resize an image while keep the four edges stretched, and the center area unchangeable for an iOS app.  It is possible in Android by 9 patch, but is there any method in `Objective-C` for doing this?

I'm looking for the `resizableImageWithCapInsets`, but it will keep the four edges unchangeable, and stretch the center area, which is not my case.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427317/how-to-stretch-a-uiimageview-without-stretching-the-center